# eval for functions and beyond

Tags: python, eval

I've been recently trying with some program synthesis.
Here, I'm generating strings, that represent valid functions. My current solution includes printing the string to stdout, storing them to a file, and calling that file from somewhere else.
However, can the functions be directly imported into a given namespace?
Assume the following example:

```
def sum2(x):
    return sum(x)

print(sum2([1,2,3]))


sstring = """
def sum3(x):
    return sum(x)
"""

eval(sstring)
print(sum3([1,2,3]))
```

Is anything like the second part (which does not work) possible? Is eval() limited to primitive expressions?

Comment: `eval` only works with expressions (things that evaluate to a value, i.e., something you can assign to a variable, `x = <some arbitrary expressions>`), `exec` takes arbitrary statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

eval's bigger brother `exec` will help you here.

```
def sum2(x):
    return sum(x)

print(sum2([1,2,3]))


sstring = """
def sum3(x):
    return sum(x)
"""

exec(sstring)
print(sum3([1,2,3]))
```

Answer (score 1):

It works if you compile it:

```
eval(compile(sstring, '', 'single'))
```

[Demo at repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/FunnyLightblueEmacs#main.py).